# Schedule update global.R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, scheduled-tasks

I have a great little shiny app which has a couple of data.frames generated from web scraping - these are done within global.r. These are accessed by different users.

While I don't need or want these to reload for every user (it would slow down the performance) - I'd like it to be scheduled to reload every 10-15 minutes or so. Is there an easy, straight forward way to get shiny to re-run the contents of global.R at regular intervals?

Comment: I use `reactivePoll` to read data from file, which in turn is updated periodically running R code, sheduled by crontab on Linux.